# How to get the unique values multiple columns for a unique value of another column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a datframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 'g_1':[0, 0, 1,0,2], 'g_2':[0, 0, 0,0,1]})
```

Now, to get the unique values of column `g_1` for all unique values of column `val`, I do something like this:

```
print(df['g_1'].groupby(df['val']).unique().apply(pd.Series))
     0
val   
a    0
b    1
c    2
```

However, I would like to add column `g_2` as well, but seems I get this error:

```
print(df[['g_1', 'g_2']].groupby(df['val']).unique().apply(pd.Series))
```

I am looking to get something like this:

```
    g_1  g_2
val   
a    0    0
b    1    0
c    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pull the non-duplicates using `df.duplicated()`.

```
df[~df.duplicated()].set_index('val')
```

Comment: To have the good result : ```df[~df.duplicated()].set_index('val')```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(df.groupby(df['val']).agg({g:lambda x:x.unique() for g in df.columns[1:]}))

#      g_1  g_2
# val          
# a      0    0
# b      1    0
# c      2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.unique` as `agg` function of `groupby`:

```
import numpy as np

>>> df.groupby('val')[['g_1', 'g_2']].agg(np.unique)
     g_1  g_2
val          
a      0    0
b      1    0
c      2    1
```